# How can I avoid race conditions at startup when directive attributes are being interpolated?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, race-condition

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8skwz9qn/) should make things more clear, but essentially I am assigning some attributes of an element (like its id) parameters in its directive:

```
myApp.directive('myDiv', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        'elementId': '@',
        'displayName': '@',
    },
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div class="my-div" id="{{elementId}}">{{displayName}}<div ng-transclude></div></div>'
}
```

})

The problem is if I do things immediately at startup, like initialize other directives, those values (e.g. elementId) are not yet interpolated.

In other words, if I get a reference to a myDiv element and print its id, immediately at startup, '{{elementId}}' is printed.  But if I wait a short time (say, one second), then the value that was passed as the value to the element-id attribute is printed (as I'd expect).

If you open the console while you view the Fiddle, you'll see that.

What am I doing wrong here?  How can I avoid this (other than a lot of really ugly timeouts at startup)?

Comment: Have you looked at ng-cloak?

Comment: @JoeEnzminger - I've used it before but this isn't a display issue.  My example is greatly simplified but the general idea is: the first time that the elementId is logged is actually it registering itself with another service.  So instead of trying to register itself with the proper id, it registers itself with '{{elementId}}'.  I don't think ng-cloak would apply here, but let me know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

You have several things incorrect. Here's a new fiddle where you can see the 'at first' log showing the correct value: http://jsfiddle.net/0mq2xv8m/

1) You should include the inner element in the template of the second. You have transclude set to true, so it's going to replace your node. This also ensures that the second directive is not going to bind before the first one is ready. I.e. since it is in the DOM alongside the outter directive, it may instantiate out of step with the wrapping directive.

```
template: '<div class="my-div" id="elementId">{{displayName}}<div my-field></div></div>'
```

2) do `id="elementId"` instead of `id="{{elementId}}"` to pass by reference instead of value

3) typically it's bad practice to fish for attributes on a parent, it's better to pass it in with 2-way binding. This holds true in any display-list oriented programming I've worked with.

Good Practice:

You should use a controller or a link function for any "init" steps. These wont run until the directive has all its attributes/scope linked. The way you have it, it is executing during the evaluation step during $scope creation (there is no scope yet). Link functions and controllers wait for $scope to become available. A controller can be used instead of a link function (I think it is clearer and easier to unit test).

```
angular.module('App').controller('someController',[], function() {
        var controller = {
            init:function(){
                console.log(elementId);
             }
        }
        controller.init();
        return controller;
});


myApp.directive('myDiv', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    controller:'someController',
    scope: {
        'elementId': '@',
        'displayName': '@',
    },
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div class="my-div" id="{{elementId}}">{{displayName}}<div ng-transclude></div></div>'
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried changing the function that I'm returning to a linking function but I get the same behavior.  And also in your example, I'm not clear on why the controller should have access to a variable called `elementId`.  What's the relationship between the scope variables of a directive and what its controller has access to?

Comment: I've read a little more and it seems that returning a function as I did is just shorthand for returning a link function.